# “AADSTS5002730: Invalid JWT token. Unsupported key for the signing algorithm” error in the on-behalf-of scenario for Azure Signal R Service token

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, adal, azure-signalr

I’m getting the above error when I’m trying to use a JWT token generated for the Azure Signal R Service (ASRS) in the on-behalf-of scenario.

**Here is a description of the flow:**
The web app is using the react-adal library to get the access token for the user. Then it connects via Signal R to the Web API A (typically via WebSockets), the Web API A extracts the passed token from the HTTP Request context, uses it for obtaining the token for Web API B in the on-behalf-of-scenario and makes an authorized HTTP call to the Web API B.  The code for getting the token for Web API B looks like this:

```
        var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(currentTokenForWebApiA, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/....");
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential, userAssertion);
```

**Problem**

It was working fine when there was no Azure Signal R Service (client was opening Signal R connection directly to the Web API A).

But after setting up in default mode the Azure Signal R Service I’m getting the *AADSTS5002730: Invalid JWT token exception.*

Azure Signal R Service works as a proxy between the client and the Web API A, according to this [ASRS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-internals) during the "negotiate" request client receives a redirect response with a new access token generated by the Azure SignalR Service SDK. Looks like it supports only **HMAC-SHA256** and **HMAC-SHA512** signing algorithms for access tokens. This new HS256 token is passed later to the Web API A and the AcquireTokenAsync method fails with the error *AADSTS5002730*.  I compared the token used without the ASRS and when the ASRS is used and indeed the singing algorithm is different, the new one which is giving the error is using  **HS256** and the old one which was working fine with on behalf-of-scenario was using **RS256** algorithm.

I can’t figure out how to make this current flow work, do you have any ideas what needs to be adjusted to make this on-behalf-of scenario working with the Azure Signal R Service? The introduction of ASRS is required due to the scale-out of the Web App A on multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if any work around is possible from below.

Firstly check for  clientId and secret  if they are correct.

If you registered the API in Azure ADAL, you need to get the token from V1 endpoint. If you registered it in the new app portal at apps.dev.microsoft.com or with MSAL library, then you need to use the V2 endpoint. (You can check the aud clain to see endpoint
(v1 or v2 ) when you validate the jwt token )

The API for MSAL is a bit different, you use a class  ConfidentialClientApplication instead of AuthenticationContext. Here is a snippet from a [sample app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2)

(or if thats not the problem )

Then It is recommended to work with asymmetric(RS256) keys but when it is desired to use symmetric  (HS256) keys you can validate jwt token and you may have to set it manually in configure services in issuersigninkey.

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidIssuer = jwtIssuer,
    ValidAudience = jwtAudience,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtKey)),

};
```

**References:**

1. [JWT: Symmetic and Asymmetic Key Authentication In ASP.NET Core | by
   Nicklas Millard | Dev Genius](https://blog.devgenius.io/jwt-authentication-in-asp-net-core-e67dca9ae3e8)
2. [asp-net-core-signalr-returns-401-unauthorized-using-azure-ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688450/asp-net-core-signalr-returns-401-unauthorized-using-azure-ad)
3. [sp-net-core-azure-ad-v1-0-jwt-authentication-invalid-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260682/asp-net-core-azure-ad-v1-0-jwt-authentication-invalid-signature)

Comment: The problem is that token is generated by Azure Signal R Service SDK which supports only HS256 and HS512 algorithms (https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/16029cbde8f45af6fbac2923c5b7102e34d5a0c9/docs/run-asp-net.md#accesstokenalgorithm) so I can't switch it to RS256. Also, error AADSTS5002730 is returned from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) security token service (STS), not from my app, so I'm not sure if there is any way of changing token validation options in the AADSTS.